# Transfer DNS Settings from Godaddy to Arvixe

Tags: php, dns, hosting, shared-hosting, reverse-dns

We have our on Godaddy and website (developed on php) and emails are running. We developed new website with asp.net, umbraco, sql 2012 which we want to host on arvixe but with same domain name.

I am actaully not an IT Admin so I am not sure about the procedure to do this.

I want to run new website on Arixe with old URL (website hosted on Godaddy) but do not want to transfer emails. Emails should run under godaddy.

1. What information I exactly need from old registerar to have configuration on arvixe?
2. While registering new hosting with Arvixe, there is an option to give (existing domain name) if we have and a checkbox with "I want to transfer my domain" Do I need to transfer my domain??

Please reply as I am not aware of this all.

Comment: Is anybody there to reply me please.

Comment: This question is not about programming. but depend on the hosting options, no need to transfer the domain, just update the dns records with the new ip. the A records and not the records for the mail.

Comment: Thank you Jan, means just I need to update dns records "A" record with new hosting. So email will be running on my old hosting?